# SQL to get the next upcoming event from a number of event entries based on event Date

Tags: sql, db2

My Database table contains the following details

```
Event Name  Event Date                  Event Status
Event 1     2013-11-11 06:10:13.24      Active
Event 2     2014-02-04 06:10:13.24      Active
Event 3     2013-11-01 06:10:13.24      Active
Event 4     2013-02-04 06:10:13.24      InActive
```

How to get the next upcoming Active Event based on the Event Date.
Is there any query which will compare the DB date with current Date and return the most recent upcoming Event. In the above case the SQL Query should return only **" Event 3 "**.

I would like to know how to put the SQL condition for date .I tried to use the  Now() function but it is giving me the below error

```
" No authorized routine named "NOW" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was    found.. SQLCODE=-440 "
```

Comment: Can we see your query?

Comment: I don't work with MySql but it appears from the error message that it does not have a now() function.  A google search of "mysql current date and time" would probably lead me to a better function.

Comment: A google search of "mysql current date and time" would confirm that MySQL has a NOW() function.

Comment: select * from MY_Table where event date >= Current TimeStamp order by event Date asc fetch first 1 rows only . This query Works fine as expected thanks for all your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from your_table
where `event date` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
and `event status` = 'Active'
order by `event date` asc
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: the event date is of Data Type TimeStamp I guess so am getting the error "No authorized routine named "NOW" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.." when I try to compare the event date with now() function. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @Suraj: Are you really using MySQL? Looks like DB2

Comment: Ok so, use `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` instead of `now()`

Comment: @Kobi Thanks please find the below query select * from MY_Table where event date >= Current TimeStamp order by event Date asc fetch first 1 rows only